# alpha support for fluent-ffmpeg complexFilter drawtext?

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha, drawtext, fluent-ffmpeg

I am able to use `ffmpeg` from a console and get a text to fade in and out, but am trying, and failing, to use the `alpha` option in the `fluent-ffmpeg`.

This works:

```
ffmpeg -i testvideo.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]drawtext=fontfile=/<full-path>/Lato-Black.ttf:text='This is a test':fontsize=12:fontcolor=e82e2e:alpha='if(lt(t,1),0,if(lt(t,2),(t-1)/1,if(lt(t,4),1,if(lt(t,5),(1-(t-4))/1,0))))':x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" outfile.mp4
```

This fails when used within a node service:

```
.complexFilter({
                filter: 'drawtext',
                options: {
                    fontfile: <font-path>
                    text: "This is a test",
                    fontsize: 18,
                    fontcolor: "ff0000",
                    alpha : if(lt(t,1),0,if(lt(t,2),(t-1)/1,if(lt(t,4),1,if(lt(t,5),(1-(t-4))/1,0)))),
                    x: 10,
                    y: 10
                }
            }, 'out')
```

> fluent-ffmpeg fails with: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error configuring
>   complex filters. Invalid argument

Is `alpha` not supported in `fluent-ffmpeg` (I can't find any documentation for it), or is it a different keyword?

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the expression in quotes:

```
alpha : "if(lt(t,1),0,if(lt(t,2),(t-1)/1,if(lt(t,4),1,if(lt(t,5),(1-(t-4))/1,0))))",
```

otherwise ffmpeg will think that the first comma (after `"if(lt(t`) concludes the filter arguments.